# Not Getting Any Output from Dockerized Celery

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, celerybeat

I have been working off of two similar tutorials ([here](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-celery-periodic-tasks/) and [here](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/celery-and-django-and-docker-oh-my/#:%7E:text=Now%20our%20app%20can%20recognize,app%20that%20Celery%20will%20run.)) trying to create a scheduled task for my Django project, but I can't seem to get any output from the Celery services.

I've added Celery and Redis to the `requirements.txt`.

```
Django==3.0.7
celery==4.4.7
redis==3.5.3
```

Added the celery, celery-beat, and redis services to the `docker-compose.yaml`.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  cache:
    image: redis:alpine

  database:
    image: "postgis/postgis"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_DEFAULT_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - database
    env_file:
      - .env

  queue:
    build: .
    command: celery -A api worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - cache
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - database

  scheduler:
    build: .
    command: celery -A api beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - cache
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - database
```

Added the `celery.py` file to the `api/api/` directory.

```python
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')

app = Celery('api')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Added the following to `api/api/__init__.py`.

```python
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Created a task in `api/server/tasks.py`.

```python
import logging

from celery import shared_task

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@shared_task
def sample_task():
    logger.debug('The sample task just ran.')
```

And added the following to `api/api/settings/base.py` (`base.py` is imported into `api/api/settings/__init__.py`).

```python
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://cache:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://cache:6379'

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'sample_task': {
        'task': 'server.tasks.sample_task',
        'schedule': crontab(),
    },
}
```

The `cache` service seems to start up fine (outputting a bunch of logs, ending with "Ready to accept connections"), but the `queue` and `scheduler` services don't seem to output anything. When I run either `docker-compose logs -f 'queue'` or `docker-compose logs -f 'scheduler'`, I get the following output.

```
Attaching to
```

I can import and run the `sample_task()` as a Celery task from the python console just fine.

```python
>>> from server.tasks import sample_task
>>> sample_task()
2020-09-10 13:47:15,020 server.tasks DEBUG    The sample task just ran.
>>> sample_task.delay()
<AsyncResult: 1594ed42-23d0-4302-8754-ba9097c170bd>
```

So what am I doing wrong? What did I miss?

---

#### Update

I made a slight bit of progress. I had been using a docker run configuration in PyCharm to `--build` the project, and didn't realize it was set to only build the `web` service; therefore the queue and scheduler services weren't being built.

After I fixed that, the queue and scheduler serves were outputting logs that complained about not having environment variables set. So after adding the `env_file` attribute to both services I can now attach to `api_queue_1` and `api_scheduler_1`, yet there is still no further output.

Answer (score 4):

```yaml
command: celery -A api worker -l info
```

```python
logger.debug('The sample task just ran.')
```

Do you see the problem?? `::facepalm::`

I was running celery with the `info` log level but the log output with the `debug` log level, therefore the `debug` logs weren't propagated.

I would've thought I'd see some kind of output from celery, even at the info log level, but I guess not. And I'm still not sure why I *was* seeing an output when I ran the celery command in the bash shell of the docker container, even before I changed the log level.